# CSS/HTML: Add line break to HTML only if screen size < xxx pixels?

Tags: html, css

so I've styled a page that looks like this:

[image]

It is responsive, but when I shrink the window size, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I want to fix the spacing in that I want a line break or two in between the buttons and the pictures below. However, I only want these line breaks if the screen size is < 767 pixels. What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you apply a `margin-bottom` to those elements in the CSS?

Comment: Line breaks are tough to do in pure CSS - the best way would be using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and a margin-bottom as suggested by PakkuDon

Comment: Current HTML and CSS missing. How is the code “responsive”, if it does not respond to viewport width changes the way you want?

Comment: Put each one in a wrapper and use `float:down`.

Answer (score 10):

In this case, I agree with everyone else, margin is a much better solution. However for cases where you need a new line, (in my case I needed to wrap a long URL in a specific place on narrow screens), you can insert a virtual break like this:

HTML:

```
ALongLineOfUnbrokenText<span class="narrow"></span>ThatNeedsToBeBroken
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .narrow {
    display: block
  }
}
```

Hopefully someone else will find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you don't want to use margins like others have suggested. You can use media queries to hide the `<br>` element above a certain screen size:

```
@media(min-width: 767px){
     br{
        display:none;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to go into your css and edit the values for the responsive layout. (*edit: Based on your question, I'm assuming you already have CSS for a responsive layout*) In the CSS for when screen size < 767 pixels add:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

Adjust the value to match what you want.

If you literally want to add a line break, you're going to probably need to implement some sort of JavaScript to `display = "block"` elements that contain `<br />` or calculate screen size and try to append `<br />` using `.innerHTML` or something crazy like that. It would be **messy**. I suggest just trying to add to the css.

Comment: Consider elaborating what that "CSS for when screen size < 767 Pixels" would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this width simple jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if( parseFloat($(window).width()) < 767 ){
        $('.container').css('margin-bottom','50px');
    }
});
```

Just replace `.container` with whatever identifier you give to those elements.

Comment: But media queries would be so much simpler (and would load faster)

Comment: I've never used them, thanks for the education, they seem very handy and are supported in majority of browsers I just read. Awesome, thanks

Comment: You should never use JavaScript if you can do it in CSS.

Comment: @MouadDebbar yeah that's my usual method of practice, I just assume most of the really dynamic CSS3 stuff is redundant for IE (guess I was wrong in this case)